# How to add the tables in mysql to the laravel migrations

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-migrations

I have a ready database created in `MySQL`. Now I created a new `Laravel 6` project. 
Is it possible to add the `tables` in `MySQL` database into the `laravel migrations` without losing the data? and is there a way to generate a migration from `MySQL` to `laravel` ?

Comment: [Xethron Migrations Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) should solve your problem. It converts a mysql database to laravel migration scripts

Comment: Yeah you are right and I tried it before I ask,  but it only works with laravel 5

Comment: It seems laravel have no this command,Maybe you need to do it by yourself. Use `mysqldump -u root -p --no-data yourdatabase > schema.sql` and read every tables in schema.sql, then convert them into the migration dir.

Comment: So you could create a dummy laravel 5 app to generate the migrations and copy them to your laravel 6/7 app

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to create the migrations (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations)

```
php artisan make:migration
```

Next run

```
php artisan migrate
```

and finaly import your data to the new tables

Comment: I think the OP is asking about tables that existed before creating the Laravel application.

Comment: I just did the "php artisan make:migration" and i got "Not enough arguments (missing: "name")."

Comment: Exactly @Rwd , The tables are existed before creating the Laravel application.

Comment: In this case, you have to make use of `if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {...}` and wrap it around the schema creation. If not, `php artisan migrate` will run in an error if the table already exists.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change some columns from your table.. you can create

```
php artisan make:migration
```

and on your migration, you can write code :

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();
});
```

be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your composer.json file.

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to check if the table exists already or not.
Do something like this in your Migration:

```
if(!Schema::hasTable('TABLE_NAME')) {
    Schema::create('TABLE_NAME', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        ...
    }
}
```

Official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-tables

Answer (score 1):

first you have to create table using cli php artisan migration:create_name_table then run the command php artisan migrate